# Example for displaying modal or card using latest react-native-navigation library

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I have been searching for a beginner example for creating modal and opening in react-native with stack navigation. But unable to find one.

I created one with below stack group

```
<Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: "modal" }}>            
            <Stack.Screen
              name="AstroCard"
              component={AstroCard}
              options={{ contentStyle:{margin:20,backgroundColor:"transparent"} }}
            />
          </Stack.Group>
```

and on press of button, I used `props.navigation.navigate("AstroCard")`

when i do this, AstroCard screen opens without the back navigation etc, but am not able to set the height or margin to make it look like a overlay. I tried card as well, but couldn't get it to work. Can someone help me with a simple example of how i can implement a card or modal like an overlay.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without navigation as well
here is the sample code for modal overlay

First add one useState like this:
[image]

Then add following code

[image]

Some styling as well

[image]

Comment: Thanks @hetali. I had this idea already, however I actually wanted to know if it can be achieved through Navigation. Still thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ramki have a look at this link might be useful to you https://www.reactnativeschool.com/master-react-navigation-v5/global-modal-screen